# How to "sscanf" in Java?

Tags: java, scanf

I have a string and I want to a) check if it matches the following format and b) extract the numbers and text into variables:

```
"x:x:x - some text" // x = some integer number
```

In, C, I would use :

```
sscanf(str1, "%d:%d:%d - %s\n", &x, &y,&z, str2);
```

How do I do the same in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean :

```
String text = "1:99:33 - some text";
boolean check = text.matches("\\d+:\\d+:\\d+ - .*");
System.out.println(check);
```

---

If you want to match exact **(one number):(two numbers):(two number)** you can use `\\d:\\d{2}:\\d{2}` instead of `\\d+:\\d+:\\d+`

details

- `\\d+` match one or more digit
- `:` literal character
- `\\d+` match one or more digit
- `:` literal character
- `\\d+` match one or more digit
- `-` one space hyphen one space
- `.*` zero or more any character

---

> ...how do I extract the numbers and the text from the string?

If you are using Java 8 you can split your input, the first input return numbers separated by `:`, the second is the text you want, so to extract the numbers, you need to split the first input again by `:` then Iterate over them and convert each one to an Integer, like this :

```
String input = "1:99:33 - some text";
String[] split = input.split(" - ");//Split using space hyphen space
String text = split[1];//this will return "some text"
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(split[0].split(":")).stream()
        .map(stringNumber -> Integer.parseInt(stringNumber))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());// this will return list of number [1, 99, 33]
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But how do I extract the numbers and the text from the string? Do I pass the same format string to a Pattern object?

Comment: @minime what did you mean `extract the numbers and the text from the string` can show us an input output example?

Comment: In the original question, the numbers and text and read into variables. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: @minime In the example i share `"1:99:33 - some text"` did you want `1:99:33` and `some text` separately ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want a) the string to match a specific format and b) to extract the numbers and text.

Comment: @minime please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47958786/edit) your question and make an example about what you want exactly

Comment: check my edit @minime hope this can help you

Comment: The code works perfectly. I need to read more data in various formats and I will use this code as a template. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The alternatve solution:

```
String input = "1:99:33 - some text";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ":");

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

StringTokenizer break the string into tokens. Where ":" is a tokens delimiter.
Output:

```
1
99
33 - some text
```